# Buying points from websites

Tags: air-travel, tips-and-tricks, loyalty-programs

In travel hacking, one common option to earn miles is buy buying them from the frequent flyer programs of airlines. I just came across a third party company that sells miles.

I was looking at some of the proposition: Asia miles, 49k miles, for 888USD. I feel this is a steal. Not only does it sell for a fraction of what the actual Asia miles website is selling for, but 49k miles is like the equivalent of taking three Hong Kong to Toronto (roundtrips)!

One question though: are they legit? Has anyone had an experience with this sort of thing?

Comment: According to TPG, Asia Miles have a 1.3c per point value, making 49000 points worth about $637.  https://thepointsguy.com/guide/monthly-valuations/

Comment: What can you get for 49K miles? A one-way HKG-YYZ flight in coach is 47K miles. The ratio is better for business and first, but availability is usually scarce. I usually only buy miles when I have a specific plan with specific flights and availabilities lined up. And remember CX miles expire.

Answer (score 8):

This is most likely a violation of terms&conditions, to which you agreed when joining the frequent flyer program. For example, [Delta SkyMiles conditions](https://www.delta.com/us/en/skymiles/program-resources/program-rules) say `Mileage Upgrade Awards may not be sold or bartered`.

If you're caught (and I don't know what are the chances) your account is likely to be deleted, along with all your miles - not only those you bought.

BTW, your valuation of the deal seems incorrect to me. 49K miles for 880$ means you're paying 1.8 cents per mile. [The travel blog OMAAT evaluates](https://onemileatatime.com/guides/value-miles-points/) Asia Miles as worth 1.2 cents each, so you may be making a bad deal. You may need to travel HKG-YYZ three times to accumulate this number of miles, but you certainly can't buy 3 such flights for 49K miles.